# Uploading One File Through AJAX Sending Empty String

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm sending one file to a PHP file through an AJAX POST request but it's sending an empty string even though if I tried to send the name only or size etc. it works just fine.

Am I doing something wrong here?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let validExt = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png']
  $('#file-upload').change(function() {
    var extension = this.files[0].type.split('/')[1]

    if (validExt.indexOf(extension) == -1) {
      swal({
        title: "!الملف غير صالح " + "(" + this.files[0].type.split('/')[1] + ")",
        text: "('jpg' , 'jpeg' , 'png') الصيغ المقبولة",
        icon: "warning",
        button: "رجوع",
      });
      return false;
    } else if (this.files[0].size > 2000000) {
      swal({
        title: "!الملف غير صالح" + "(" + (this.files[0].size / 1024 / 1024)
          .toFixed(2) + "MB)",
        text: "لا يمكن ان يزيد حجم الملف عن 2 ميغابايت",
        icon: "warning",
        button: "رجوع",
      });
      return false;
    }

    var file_data = $('#file-upload').prop('files');
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('files', file_data);
    $.ajax({
      url: "edit-product.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: file_data,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(form_data);
        // $(document).ready(function(e) {
        //     setTimeout(function() {
        //         location.reload();
        //     }, 2000)
        // });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<input accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg" type="file" class="form-control-file d-none" id="file-upload" name="file-upload">
```

Comment: You need to upload the FormData object, not the `Files` collection. Change `data: file_data` to `data: form_data`. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: TYPO `data: file_data,` should I think be `data: form_data ,`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i did `data: form_data` same result.

Comment: Try `data: new FormData($('#yourFormHere')[0])`

Comment: Or `var file_data = $('#file-upload').prop('files')[0];`. I don’t think you can stuff `files` into FormData.append directly, you need to do it for each entry in that collection individually.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan im not sending Form, im only sending one single Image. tho still doesn't work :(

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i think the problem by the sending request

Comment: `console.log(file_data)` giving me exactly what i want (file:name,file:type,file:size...) but if i make it in the `data: file_data` sends `null`

Comment: How have you determined its null on the server side?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it's not even reaching to the server side, in the `console.log : POST` it's sending nothing

Comment: Then that means the server generated an error when it received the request - it's a server side problem in your PHP, not the JS. Open the console and look at the request being made in devtools. Debug its response text and status code.